# try to getting wall xml same element value and then apply on other xml

Tags: php, xml, xpath

this is my general.xml file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
    <numFound>10</numFound>
    <QTime>4</QTime>
    <result>
        <distance>1071.59873299109</distance>
        <name>Irungattukottai</name>
    </result>
    <result>
            <distance>1892.33578431928</distance>
            <name>Valapuram</name>
       </result>
</results>
```

region.xml:-

```
<childrens>
    <child_5068 entity_id="5069" value="Irungattukottai" parent_id="4068"/>
    <child_5068 entity_id="7140" value="Valapuram" parent_id="4068"/>
</childrens>
```

product.xml:-

```
<products>
  <product_id value="1">
    <tab_id value="351">
      <tab_name value="test1"/>
      <dist_region value="5069"/>
      <dist_region value="5069"/>
      <dist_region value="5069"/>
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
  <product_id value="2">
    <tab_id value="352">
      <tab_name value="test2"/>
      <dist_region value="4457"/>
      <dist_region value="7140"/>
      <dist_region value="5069"/>
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
</products>
```

i have this three xml file i want to try something like this.
in general.xml file element `<name>Irungattukottai</name>`
if this name is exit in `region.xml` then get there `entity_id`
if entity_id is exit in `product.xml` then return there `product_id` element attribute  value...

i am try this code:-

```
<?php
$g = file_get_contents('general.xml');
$r = file_get_contents('region.xml');
$p = file_get_contents('product.xml');

$general = simplexml_load_string($g);
$region = simplexml_load_string($r);
$product = simplexml_load_string($p);

$name = (string)$general->result->name;

if (strlen(trim($name))==0) exit('name not found');

list($entity) = $region->xpath("//*[@value='$name']/@entity_id");
$entity=(string)$entity;

if (strlen(trim($entity))==0) exit('entity_id not found');

list($prid) = $product->xpath("//dist_region[@value='$entity']/ancestor::product_id/@value");
$prid=(string)$prid;

echo "City Name:- $name, Entity_id:- $entity, Product_id:- $prid";
?>
```

this code is work perfact but only one value eg:-`general.xml` has two root in first `<name>Irungattukottai</name>` and in second root`<name>Valapuram</name>` 
but my code is work only get first element not try to get wall xml file...

this is my corrent output:-

```
city Name:- Irungattukottai, Entity_id:- 5079, Product_id:- 1
```

but i want to this type of output:-

```
city Name:- Irungattukottai, Entity_id:- 5079, Product_id:- 1
city Name:- Valapuram , Entity_id:- 7140, Product_id:- 2
```

Comment: try to do `print_r($general);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with use of above both answer its possible try this:-

```
  <?php
    foreach($general->result as $row){
    if(isset($row->name)){
    //create one variable and store in value.
    $name = $row->name;
     //all you code for region.xml and then for product.xml

    }
    echo "name:- $name,Entity:- $entity, product:- $prid"."<br>";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the array of $general.

**Try to do :**

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($general);
echo '</pre>';
```

Check if you get an array with all the elements as in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code to get general.xml feeds is ok.

You can get the name as

```
$name1 = (string)$general->result[0]->name;
$name2 = (string)$general->result[1]->name;
or you can use loop to get name one by one.

<?php
foreach($general->result as $row){
if(isset($row->name)){
  // do your logic here for region.xml and then for product.xml
}
}
?>
```

Comment: i am try foreach loop something like this :-           `foreach($general->result->name as $row){
list($entity) = $region->xpath("//*[@value='$row']/@entity_id");
$entity=(string)$entity;

list($prid) = $product->xpath("//dist_region[@value='$entity']/ancestor::product_id/@value");
$prid=(string)$prid;

echo "City Name:- $row, Entity_id:- $entity, Product_id:- $prid";
}
`

Comment: If you will print your result $general then you can see that $general->result->name is not array.Array is $general->result.$general->result->name will give you the first name only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file( 'general.xml' );
$cities = $xml->xpath( '//result/name' );

$cityCount = count( $cities );
if( $cityCount ) {
    $region = simplexml_load_file( 'region.xml' );
    foreach( $cities as $city ) {
        $regions = $region->xpath( '//*[@value="'. ( string ) $city . '"]/@entity_id' );
        if( count ( $regions ) ) {
            $product = simplexml_load_file( 'products.xml' );
            $products = $product->xpath( '//dist_region[@value="' . ( string ) $regions[ 0 ][ 'entity_id' ] . '"]/ancestor::product_id/@value' );
            if( count( $products ) ) {
                foreach( $products as $p ) {
                    echo 'city Name:- ' . ( string ) $city . ', Entity_id:- ' . ( string ) $regions[ 0 ][ 'entity_id' ] . ', Product_id:- ' . $p[ 'value' ] . "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
city Name:- Irungattukottai, Entity_id:- 5069, Product_id:- 1
city Name:- Irungattukottai, Entity_id:- 5069, Product_id:- 2
city Name:- Valapuram, Entity_id:- 7140, Product_id:- 2
```